# Calculate: $\int_{\gamma} \log z dz$, $\gamma$ be the negatively oriented arc of the circle that begins from $-2i$ and ends on $2i$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, vector-analysis, contour-integration

Let $\gamma$ be the negatively oriented  arc of the circle beginning from $-2i$ and ends on $2i$ .
Evaluate the curve integral $\int_{\gamma} \log z dz$. It is obvious to me that I should evaluate this integral by definition and not by the fundamental theorem (because there is not exist $F$ such that $F'(z)=\log z$).
Any help or ideas please to calculate this integral will be nice!! Thanks

Comment: So, taking $z=2e^{i \theta}$, what does this integral look like in terms of $\theta$?

Comment: I took the parametrisation $\gamma (t)=2e^{-it}, t\in [\pi/2,3\pi/2]$ but I cannot evaluate later the integral. Do you mean to change variables?

Comment: $F(z)=z\log(z)-z$

Comment: You can not use $F$ to compute the integral because the curve intersectes $(-\infty, 0] $.

Comment: @mjqxxxx ??????

Comment: Yes, I meant to change variables.  But since you have the integral of $\log z$ available, you should use that.  If you actually mean for the log to be evaluated on the principal branch (so, discontinuous at the negative real axis), then just break the integral into two pieces... from $-2i$ to $-2$, and then from $-2$ to $2i$.  Each piece can use the fundamental theorem.

Comment: @mjqxxxx but if I break the integral into two pieces again one of two pieces intersects the negative real axis at $-2$ as a result I cannot take the fundamental  theorem. I am confused

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a function in the complex plane, the logarithm is multivalued, with infinitely many branches.  The log of a complex number $re^{i\theta}$, depending on the branch, can take on any of the values $\log r + i\theta + 2\pi i k$ ($k\in\mathbb{Z}$). The same is true for its integral, $F(z)=z\log z - z$.  So if $\gamma:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is a curve from $\gamma(0)=z_0$ to $\gamma(1)=z_1$, then
$$
\int_{\gamma}\log z\;dz=F(z)\big\vert_{z_0}^{z_1}=F(z_1)-F(z_0)=(z_1\log z_1-z_0\log z_0) - (z_1-z_0),
$$
as long as the curve stays on the same branch of the logarithm (e.g., if the entire curve avoids the negative real axis).  Note that the first term in the integral doesn't have the same value on every branch... we still need to specify the branch.  I'm assuming you are asking about the principal branch, where $\log re^{i\theta}=\log r + i\theta$ for $\theta\in(-\pi,\pi)$.  In particular, we have $\log 2i=\log 2 + i\pi/2$, $\log (-2i)=\log 2 - i\pi/2$, and $\log (-2\pm i\varepsilon)=\log 2 \pm i\pi$.

In this case, where the curve crosses the negative real axis at a single point, we can just divide the integral into two pieces:
$$
\begin{eqnarray}
\int_{\gamma}\log z \;dz &=& \int_{\gamma_1}\log z \; dz+\int_{\gamma_2}\log z \; dz \\ &=&\left(F(-2-i\varepsilon)-F(-2i)\right)+\left(F(2i)-F(-2+i\varepsilon)\right)
\\ &=&\left(-2\log(-2-i\varepsilon)-(-2i)\log(-2i)\right) + \left(2i\log 2i -(-2)\log(-2+i\varepsilon)\right)-4i
\\ &=& -2(\log2 - i\pi)+2i(\log 2 - i\pi / 2)+2i(\log2 + i\pi/2)+2(\log 2 + i\pi)-4i
\\ &=& -2\log 2 + 2i\pi + 2i\log 2 + \pi + 2i\log 2 - \pi + 2\log 2 + 2i\pi - 4i
\\ &=& 4i(-1+\pi+\log 2) \approx 11.338959 i.
\end{eqnarray}
$$
You are getting the naive value of $F(2i)-F(-2i)$, plus the discontinuity at the branch cut, which is $F(-2+i\varepsilon)-F(-2-i\varepsilon)=4i\pi$.

Comment: The points $-2\pm i\varepsilon$ don't belong on curve $\gamma$. Ιnstead of taking the points $-2+ i\varepsilon$ and $-2-i\varepsilon$ I suggest you to take a $w_0$ and $w_1$, respectively such that $w_0$ being a point on the curve $\gamma$  a bit upper from $-2$ and $w_1$ being a point on the curve $\gamma$  a bit lower from $-2$. And then we take the limits as $w_0, w_1\to -2$. What do you say?

Comment: Sure, that's what I'm doing.  I get your point, but the distance between $-2\pm i\varepsilon$ and the curve is $O(\varepsilon^2)$, so the result will be the same.  If you work with the parametrized form of the curve, this will be handled automatically.

Comment: Thanks for helping me, I appreciate it